# How to use Universal Windows runtime api in .netframework project

Tags: c#, authentication, winapi, windows-runtime

I am tring to use WebAuthenticationCoreManager API in windows agent service (.netframework 4.7.2) to get token, but cannot import the package successfully:

1. Install `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` package according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance, the error is no `Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core` package.
2. Reference Windows.winmd file as below code:

```
<Reference Include="Windows">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.18362.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

There are two kinds of errors:

a. When use `await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync($"https://{info.pszIdpDomain}");`, the error is  `Error   CS4036  'IAsyncOperation<WebAccountProvider>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<WebAccountProvider>' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)`

b. When use `WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync($"https://{info.pszIdpDomain}").GetResults()`, it throws expection:  BindingFlags = Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_BindingFlags cannot be called in this context.

Comment: Just do `var prov = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync($"https://{info.pszIdpDomain}").AsTask();` AsTask is an extension method

Comment: @SimonMourier The error is `
Error CS1061 'IAsyncOperation<WebAccountProvider>' does not contain a definition for 'AsTask' and no accessible extension method 'AsTask' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<WebAccountProvider>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I am wondering if the reference is correct

Comment: You shouldn't need Windows.winmd at all. Just add the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts nuget (and make sure you're using PackageReference, not packages.config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Comment: Thanks!  it works after install System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime and System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml manually, and then install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.